# JS: Class extends value is not a function or null

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, ecmascript-6, webdriver-io

This is how I'm trying to build my first page object for login testing using WebdriverIO

But I'm getting the error `ERROR: Class extends value #<Page> is not a function or null` on line 3 of `login.page.js`.

I don't see, what I'm doing wrong... Is there any path or filename wrong?

**/tests/specs/login.specs.js**

```
var expect = require('chai').expect
var LoginPage = require('../pageobjects/login.page')

describe('login form', function () {
  it('should deny access with wrong creds', function () {
    LoginPage.open()
    LoginPage.username.setValue('foo')
    LoginPage.password.setValue('bar')
    LoginPage.submit()
    expect(LoginPage.flash.getText()).to.contain('Your username is invalid!')
  })
})
```

**/tests/pageobjects/page**

```
'use strict'
class Page {
  constructor() {
    this.title = 'My Page'
  }
  open(path) {
    browser.url('/' + path)
  }
}
module.exports = new Page()
```

**/tests/pageobjects/login.page.js**

```
'use strict'
var Page = require('./page')
class LoginPage extends Page {
  get username () { return browser.element('#username') }
  get password () { return browser.element('#password') }
  get form () { return browser.element('#login') }
  get flash () { return browser.element('#flash') }

  open () {
    super.open('login')
  }

  submit () {
    this.form.submitForm()
  }
}
module.exports = new LoginPage()
```

Comment: You're exporting an instance of a class not a class itself

Comment: I don't see the point...

Comment: try `module.exports = Page`

Comment: Then I'll get `ERROR: Class constructors cannot be invoked without 'new'`

Comment: And I guess you're getting that in `login.specs.js` because you need to change also `module.exports = new LoginPage()` to `module.exports = LoginPage` and in `login.specs.js` make an instance of `LoginPage`.

Comment: No, I'm getting it in `page` although I tried to remove `new`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149263/discussion-between-user3142695-and-gerardo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Gerardo, your're exporting an instance of the class and note the class itself. Try these changes:

**/tests/pageobjects/page**

```
module.exports = Page;
```

**/tests/pageobjects/login.page.js**

```
module.exports = LoginPage;
```

**/tests/specs/login.specs.js**

```
var LoginPage = new (require('../pageobjects/login.page'))();
```

or

```
var LoginPage = require('../pageobjects/login.page');
var instanceLoginPage = new LoginPage();
```

Comment: Sir, or whether we can instance, that class in the constructor ?
... class {
  constructor () {
    this.instanceLoginPage = new LoginPage();
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
module.exports.Page = Page
```

then in login.page

```
var Page = require('./page.js').Page
```